# jQuery iframe issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, image-gallery

I was working on a picture slider (using the AmazingSlider engine) for a client and tested it in Chrome and Firefox - all works well. Then comes along IE, with its incessant perchance for bugs. And lo and behold, the gallery slider doesn't even work in it except show the navigation bar.

I'm not sure where is going wrong and have gotten the impression IE has issues with iframes and jquery being loaded inside. Something to do with DOM in IE?

I even tried referencing the jquery engine inside the iframe head, and that didn't work too. The only thing that seemed to work was to make the slider outside of the iframe, which goes *against* what I intend the gallery section of the website to be.

Is there any way around this? Thanks for your time.

(FYI Gallery link can be found at http://beecroft.byteserve.com.au/main-IE.php in the home section of the website)

Comment: jQuery v1.6.4? Might be time to upgrade since that is 2+ years old now.

Comment: Remove `jquery.js` as you already added `jquery-1.9 version`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for pointing it out. Images now appear, but IE has refresh issues every now n then.